# How to setup setupProxy.js file in react typescript project

Tags: react-typescript, http-proxy-middleware

I'm using React CRA-typescript template and want to configure proxy manually using http-proxy-middleware

This is my setupProxy.js

[image: This is my setupProxy.js]

And this is my fetch request
[image]

**But proxy is not redirecting to correct url and still using localhost.**
This how request send in browser

[image]

**Anyone know why this is happening or am I doing it wrong here?**